# How to change the Boolean value from Retrofit onResponse method

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

```
 public Boolean getOtp(String mobile, String otp, String accessToken){
    Boolean success = false;

    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progress.animate();
     Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
             .baseUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.baseURL))
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .build();
    APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Call<statusResponse> call = apiService.checkOtp(mobile,accessToken , otp);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<statusResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<statusResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            statusResponse sp = response.body();

            if (sp.getStatus().equals("1")) {
                success = true;
                Log.e("Response ", sp.getText() + valueOf(success);
            } else {

                Log.e("Response Failed", String.valueOf(sp));
                /*Snackbar.make(cl, "Failed to update, please try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
            }
            }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    return success;
}
```

Boolean was showing error to declare it as final

> final Boolean[] success = {false};
>   return success[0]

Then it is returning false every time. 
response is

> {"status":"1","text":"OTP successfull"}

Comment: first check is your call hitting to the server or not ??   use `response.isSuccessful() is coming true or not `.

Comment: paste your response here..

Comment: Am getting proper response {"status":"1","text":"OTP successfull"} am getting the Log as "Response OTP successfulnull"

Comment: Try calling call.execute instead of asynchronous method - call.enqueue ...

Comment: @AditiParikh this would only work if the shown code is not executed on the main thread.

Comment: call.execute also giving the false.

Answer (score 2):

You are making an asynchronous call. The `onResponse` method will be executed only when the call is finished. Your `return success` statement is executed long before that and therefore returns `false`.